# Schmitt trigger circuit design suggestions

Tags: schmitt-trigger

[image]

There is a simple switching sensor which will be wired to a circuit by a BNC cable as shown in the above illustration.

As you see, when the switch is ON the potential at the point "A" will be high; and when the switch is OFF the potential will be zero. Pulse freq will vary from 1Hz to 40Hz.

For some reasons, I need this ON-OFF pulse output to be sharp and clean. So I want to take the point "A" as an input to a circuitry(Schmitt trigger) and obtain a better output.

I need advice when designing a Schmitt trigger circuit which satisfies the following expectations for the output pulse:

It shouldn't bounce, it should be immune to noise and it should be as sharp as possible(very short rising falling edges). 
And it should work for 5V to 12V Vcc range.

I would appreciate any generic circuit or idea.

Comment: Nothing is ever immune to noise. Also, just do some classic debouncing and whack a schmitt trigger IC after it, not sure what the big deal here is.

Comment: a known design would help

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7MKL7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1/R2 and R3/R4 are the voltage dividers to set trigger offset and hysteresis, R5/C1 is the input low-pass for debouncing (\$f_c = \frac{1}{2 \pi R C}\$). Output is inverted, obviously.

I used V3 to model bouncing and to test the low-pass, you might want to use different resistor/cap values.

Comment: Thanks. Does V2 correspond to the input "A" in my illustration? Is it ok  for 5 to 12Vcc supply range as well with the same values?

Comment: and can I use LM2903 instead? Is TL081 better?

Comment: Im having 1.8V offset at the output low in LTspice simulation. How make low around 0V?

Comment: V2+V3 correspond to your input A. Please consider that your "pull-up" must be a magnitude bigger than 330 Ohms, or your switch will not pull A down enough.
I didn't choose an OpAmp, that's up to you. If you need 0V low, you need an OpAmp that can handle rail-to-rail voltage, the LM2903 should probably do (~400mV).

Comment: thanks I opened a new question hope u might have an input: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/256554/debouncing-and-hysteresis-questions-about-a-schmitt-trigger-circuit